al intentar descargar un forma mkv dentro de webview se descarga con formato .bin
cuando intento realizar una descarga de archivos como .mkv .avi .txt y otros se descargan con formato .bin dentro de mi webview , tengo esto pero no logro resolverlo
intente resolverlo pero sin resultados
es webview java
cuando intento realizar una descarga de archivos como .mkv .avi .txt y otros se descargan con formato .bin dentro de mi webview , tengo esto pero no logro resolverlo
intente resolverlo pero sin resultados
es webview java
private WebView webView;
private FrameLayout adContainerView;
private AdView adView;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StatusBarUtils.checkStatusBarTransparency(this, Config.JSON_URL);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    adContainerView = findViewById(R.id.ad_container);

   
    String cellEValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("cellEValue");
    boolean shouldBlockAds = "1".equals(cellEValue);

    if (!shouldBlockAds) {
        // Load the banner ad
        loadBanner();
    }

   
    setupWebView(webView);

    
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
          
            String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType);

           
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            String cookies = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
            request.setTitle(filename);  
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);  // Set destination filename

            
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading file: " + filename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    // web
    webView.loadUrl("https://archive.org/details/the-dick-van-dyke-show-season-1-of-5-mkv");
}

